# How to specify the package when looking up a help reference page for a function?

Tags: r, emacs, package, ess

How does one look up the help manual page for a function and specify the package in R? For example, count appears in both seqinr and plyr. If I want to look up count in plyr, what's the command? I've tried a few obvious (but wrong) guesses such as "?plyr::count"

**EDIT:**
When I do ?count, I get the following message:

```
Help on topic 'count' was found in the following packages:

  Package               Library
  plyr                  /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library
  seqinr                /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library
```

When I do ?plyr::count, I get:

```
No documentation for 'plyr::count' in specified packages and libraries:
you could try '??plyr::count'
```

When I do ?plyr:::count, I get:

```
No documentation for 'plyr:::count' in specified packages and libraries:
you could try '??plyr:::count'
```

Adding two question marks also gets me a no documentation found error as well. Looking up help for non-ambiguous funcitons is working fine (e.g. ?plot)

This is with R 2.15.0 on OSX running in emacs + ESS.

Comment: `?plyr::count` works for me on R-2.15.0 (WinXP 32-bit).

Comment: `?plyr::count` and `?seqinr::count` both work for me. It looks like you can also do `help("count", package = "plyr")`. Have you installed the packages? What error message do you get?

Comment: @flodel: my bet is that their [computer exploded](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.general/262206).

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich :-) I almost wet myself laughing at Greg's response earlier today.

Comment: Thanks for the comments - see new edits...

Comment: Ok, so you left out the one **key** bit of information. What we are showing you doesn't seem to be working in Emacs+ESS on my system either. I suggest you take this up on the ESS mailing list. I'll also re-tag here to see if anyone with Emacs+ESS fu can help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `package=` argument to `help`:

```
help("count", package="plyr")
```

Comment: This actually works! but why is everyone saying that the other options should work as well? The behavior is a little different though - this displays the help within the R console instead of in a separate emacs frame. Is there a way to do this with the ? notation?

Comment: @daj: I have no idea, since I don't use Emacs.

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to do this is:

```
?plyr::count
?plyr:::count
```

See `?"?"` for details - both examples are shown.

Both work for me with both packages loaded and even without the package loaded. That begs the question if you have the packages installed?

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich You're right; over-interpreted that both versions are documented. Will edit that out.

Comment: Yes, I have the packages installed.

Answer (score 3):

You were close, you need three : `:::`

```
?seqinr:::count # for seqinr
?plyr:::count # for plyr
```